# are succinct struct initializers possible

Tags: rust

say I have

```
struct S1{
  name:&'s str,
  start : u8,
  end : u8,
}
```

I would like to make an array of them

in C and c++ I can go (a v common pattern )

```
  S1 arr[] ={
     {"foo",1,2},
     {"bar",4,5},
  }
```

Seems like this must be in rust

```
  let arr = [
     S1{name:"foo", start:1, end: 2},
     S1{name:"bar", start:4, end: 5},
    ]
```

The problem here is a) its a lot of typing b) the information in the table is drowned out by the repeated struct and field names.

I have worked out that I can use tuples

```
let arr = [("foo",1,2),("bar",3,4)]
```

but I loose the ability to refer to the fields by name.

Did I miss something? Maybe a helper macro? (3 days into writing rust so apologies if FAQ or plain dumb)

Comment: You can write your own [macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html), but if this is static data which is defined once and never changes (within each execution of your software) then I'd recommend moving these raw data into a text file, then writing a function to read them into a Vec. Hide the Vec (using [modules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-02-defining-modules-to-control-scope-and-privacy.html)) so that it cannot be accessed mutably, and you ought to be as safe as you would be with a hardcode array. But I'm fairly new to Rust, too, so here's hoping some experts join in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose to use a constructor function instead, which will be equivalent to the tuple version but with an extra prefix due to the function calls:

```
let arr = [S1::new("foo",1,2), S1::new("bar",3,4)]
```

If you would like to emulate the tuple array / C++ braced and have nothing besides the initial values inside the array, you can use a macro to expand a list of argument tuples/groups into a constructor call:

```
let arr = expand![
    ("foo", 1, 2), 
    ("bar", 3, 4), 
    ("baz", 5, 6), 
    ("qux", 7, 8)
];
```

The macro `expand!` is declared as follows:

```
macro_rules! expand {
    ( $( ($name:expr, $start:expr, $end:expr) ),* ) => {
        [ $( S1 { name: $name, start: $start, end: $end } ),* ]
    }
}
```

If you would like to use braces instead of parentheses to group the arguments, simply replace the parentheses enclosing `$name:expr, $start:expr, $end:expr` in the matcher with braces. Note that you can call a macro with braces, parentheses or rectangular brackets, so you could could make it look exactly like the C++ version, barring the macro call:

```
let arr = expand! {
    {"foo", 1, 2}, 
    {"bar", 3, 4}, 
    {"baz", 5, 6}, 
    {"qux", 7, 8}
};
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=02a895ae16c98444d919406061e3e195)

Comment: ty, boy have I got a lot to learn (v experienced c++ dev deciding to give rust a go for a non trivial project - for fun). That macro stuff looks key (as opposed to c++ where 'real programmers done do macros anymore')

Answer (score 1):

I agree it can be unwieldy to write out the whole list.
I find that I only have that kind of situation in tests.
In that case what I do is write a tiny local function
above the list and use that. If I end up reusing it in a
few tests, I might move it to the test module scope.
Either way, because we've controlled the scope of the function
using a very short name doesn't feel so bad.

```
pub fn main() {
    fn s(name: &str, start: u8, end: u8) -> S1 {
        S1 { name, start, end }
    }
    let arr = [s("foo", 1, 2), s("bar", 4, 5)];
    println!("arr={:?}", arr2)
}
```

You can see a complete working example in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1fad455a0c27de9b9291eb36f7e8d84f).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing.

using the macro suggested by @EvilTak and mixing in https://docs.rs/phf/0.8.0/phf/

I got this

```
macro_rules! expand {
    ( $( ($name:expr, $start:expr, $end:expr) ),* ) => {
        [ $( RegDef { name: $name, start: $start, end: $end } ),* ]
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct RegDef{
    name:&'static str,
    start: usize,
    end: usize
}

static REGDEF_MAP: phf::Map<&'static str, &[RegDef]> = phf_map!{
    "rkcs" => &expand![
        ("err", 15, 16),
        ("he", 14, 15),
        ("scp", 13, 14),
        ("inhib", 11, 12),
        ("fmt", 10, 11),
        ("sse", 8, 9),
        ("rdy", 7, 8),
        ("ide", 6, 7),
        ("mex", 4, 6),
        ("func", 1, 4),
        ("go", 0, 1)
    ],
    "rker" => &expand![
        ("dre", 15, 16),
        ("ovr", 14, 15),
        ("wlo", 13, 14),
        ("ske", 12, 13),
        ("pge", 11, 12),
        ("nxm", 10, 11),
        ("dlt", 9, 10),
        ("tme", 8, 9),
        ("nxd", 7, 8),
        ("nxc", 6, 7),
        ("nxs", 5, 6),
        ("cse", 1, 2),
        ("wce", 0, 1)
    ],
    "rkds" => &expand![
        ("drid", 13, 16),
        ("pwr", 12, 13),
        ("rk05", 11, 12),
        ("dru", 10, 11),
        ("seeki", 9, 10),
        ("scok", 8, 9),
        ("rdy", 7, 8),
        ("ardy", 6, 7),
        ("wp", 5, 6),
        ("scsa", 4, 5),
        ("sc", 0, 4)
    ],
    "rkda" => &expand![
        ("drv", 13, 16),
        ("cyl", 5,13),
        ("sur", 4, 5),
        ("sec", 0, 4)
    ],

};
```